# Upserts a data extension row using Rest Api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

When I am try to insert data into a data extension using REST API I'm getting an error.

**Api Doc:**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/putDataExtensionRowByKey.htm

**Put Url :**
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:4D58A264-3B49-44C4-A350-14D2D0A7D39B/rows/CustomerID:123

**Post Data:**

```
{
    "values":{
            "Interest":"1et.com"
             }
}
```

In the **Header** I provide `AccessToken`.

**Response** is:

```
{
    "message": "Primary key 'CustomerID' does not exist.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

But I have `CustomerID` as a Primary Key on that Data Extension

[image]

**Total Records In DE:**
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78200/discussion-on-question-by-saravanan-m-upserts-a-data-extension-row-using-rest-ap).

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the error?